# Is this normal memory behavior?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

When my Android app is running idle (i.e. doing nothing). The allocated memory slowly increases until there is no more 'Free' memory and when it hits the ceiling, the memory gets garbage collected I think.

Please look at the Image below.

[image: memory over time]

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // FIREBASE
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

    // FACEBOOK
    private CallbackManager FBcallbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        FBcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

        loginButton.registerCallback(FBcallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavigationActivity.class);

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {

                    Log.d(TAG, user.getDisplayName());

                    // User is signed in
                    // if so start next activty and close this one
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is logged in");

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is logged out");
                }

            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        FBcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
        }



    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {

        final AuthCredential authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());

        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Authentication successful");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Authentication not successful");
                    Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
}
}
```

**hprof**

[image: hprof]

**MAT give me these problems:**

- *Problem Suspect 1*

74.846 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "" occupy 6.777.960 (29,27%) bytes.

- *Problem Suspect 2*

33 instances of "java.lang.DexCache", loaded by "" occupy 5.293.808 (22,86%) bytes.

- *Problem Suspect 3*

19 instances of "long[]", loaded by "" occupy 3.970.432 (17,15%) bytes.

- *Problem Suspect 4*

5.082 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "" occupy 2.811.328 (12,14%) bytes.

Comment: what does your app do? It could be a custom view that's leaking memory on every drawing pass, or it could be new object creation inside a loop you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not normal. Sounds like you're creating new objects all the time.